# How to completely restart a python program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lego-mindstorms

For a project, i used a Raspberry Pi (running dexter industries modified raspbian) and Brick Pi to run lego motors. I wroted a program with python and it works great and all, but i need the entire program to run repeatedly if the pressure sensor was not pressed. I tried calling the function sensorValue() (which detects whether the pressure sensor was being pushed) under while True:. But once i did that stuff became weird. It would just continue to repeat indefinitely and even if i pushed the sensor, the recurring 0 would turn to 1 but it wouldn't call the next function i need it to run.

Please help, this is my first time actually using python to write anything and i am a massive beginner so any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Thanks Again

```
from BrickPi import *

BrickPiSetup()
BrickPi.MotorEnable[PORT_A] = 1
BrickPi.SensorType[PORT_4] = TYPE_SENSOR_TOUCH

BrickPiSetupSensors()

def sensorValue():
    result = BrickPiUpdateValues()
    if not result :
        print BrickPi.Sensor[PORT_4]
    time.sleep(.01)
    if BrickPi.Sensor[PORT_4] == 0:

def programBody():

    print ("program rest/pause")
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[PORT_A] = 0
    BrickPiUpdateValues()
    time.sleep(3) 

    print ("reminder/alarm = 200 value")
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[PORT_A] = 200
    ot = time.time()
    while(time.time() - ot <3):
        BrickPiUpdateValues()
        time.sleep(.01)

    print ("reminder/alarm = 125 value")
    BrickPi.MotorSpeed[PORT_A] = 125
    ot = time.time()
    while(time.time() - ot <3):
        BrickPiUpdateValues()
        time.sleep(.01)

sensorValue()  #I would put while True: here but...

if BrickPi.Sensor[PORT_4]:
    print "program successfully initiatied"
    programBody()
```

Comment: couldn't you do while x == 1 run program then when ran successfully have it set it to 0 and then if the condition isn't met then return it to 1.

Comment: @thesonyman101 really sorry but I'm a total noob at this, never done any actual python, could you help me out here and run me through with what you wrote? Thanks

Comment: sure I made something real quick

Comment: So I'm going to rewrite your program what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @thesonyman101 the program runs and if the pressure sensors is pressed, the motors start running ( programBody() ). if nothings pressed then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import BrickPi,time

BrickPiSetup()
BrickPi.MotorEnable[PORT_A] = 1
BrickPi.SensorType[PORT_4] = TYPE_SENSOR_TOUCH

BrickPiSetupSensors()

z = 0
def mainprogram():
    print ("running")
    while x == 1:
        z = z + 1
        print ("the plate has been pressed for %s seconds" % z)
        time.sleep(1)

while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
    if BrickPi.Sensor[PORT_4]:
        print "program successfully initiatied"
        mainprogram()
```